# pandas apply zscore on certain columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
    DATE        value1      value2      value3      value4
0   2020-01-06  1432.474761 96.215891   1488.882633 96.015154
1   2020-01-07  1023.868069 97.645627   1054.100066 97.536370
2   2020-01-08  837.560896  98.281260   788.085172  98.445618
3   2020-01-09  1351.789373 96.560701   1800.800979 95.025800
4   2020-01-10  1102.373631 97.430358   991.444011  97.799854
```

I want to compute `zscore` for each column:

```py
from scipy.stats import zscore
df.drop(columns=["DATE"])
df.apply(zscore)
```

The above works fine except that I have to drop `DATE` column. If I select a column as below:

```py
from scipy.stats import zscore
df["value1"].apply(zscore)
```

it gives me an error:

```
AxisError: axis 0 is out of bounds for array of dimension 0
```

Is there a way I can run `apply(zscore)` on selected columns?

Answer (score 2):

You need to chain your two commands (`drop` is not in place):

```
from scipy.stats import zscore

df.drop(columns=["DATE"]).apply(zscore)
```

To update in place, pass the output to [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
df.update(df.drop(columns=["DATE"]).apply(zscore))
```

Output:

```
         DATE    value1    value2    value3    value4
0  2020-01-06  1.301132 -1.352202  0.718674 -0.756342
1  2020-01-07 -0.578415  0.560289 -0.463927  0.455532
2  2020-01-08 -1.435408  1.410546 -1.187483  1.179883
3  2020-01-09  0.929988 -0.890966  1.567087 -1.544509
4  2020-01-10 -0.217298  0.272334 -0.634351  0.665436
```

Other useful options to select your columns: [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) and [`select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html)

```
df.filter(like='value').apply(zscore)

df.select_dtypes('number').apply(zscore)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert `DATE` column to index first:

```
df = df.set_index('DATE').apply(zscore).reset_index()
```

Or converting all columns without first:

```
df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.iloc[:, 1:].apply(zscore)
```

Or generate columns names:

```
#all columns without DATE
cols = df.columns.difference(['DATE'])

#all columns contains value
cols = df.filter(like='value').columns
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(zscore)
```

---

```
print (df)
         DATE    value1    value2    value3    value4
0  2020-01-06  1.301132 -1.352202  0.718674 -0.756342
1  2020-01-07 -0.578415  0.560289 -0.463927  0.455532
2  2020-01-08 -1.435408  1.410546 -1.187483  1.179883
3  2020-01-09  0.929988 -0.890966  1.567087 -1.544509
4  2020-01-10 -0.217298  0.272334 -0.634351  0.665436
```